# C# : Is it possible to initialize exception of the same type when some instance of exception is passed in?

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I want to prevent all exceptions thrown by referenced libraries from escaping my library. I am doing this by filtering all functions through try catch which wraps exceptions if they are not `MyException` type. The problem that I have is that in my wrap function if the exception is `MyException` type I end up loosing my original stack trace since I end up re-throwing the same exception from a new place and don't embed the exception that was originally thrown, since the stack trace gets recorded from a new place where exception is re-thrown the stack trace of original `throw` is lost.

```
public static Exception Wrap(Exception exception)
{
    Exception exceptionToReturn;
    if (exception is MyException)
    {
        exceptionToReturn = exception;
    }
    else
    {
        exceptionToReturn = new MyException("Referenced library exception wrapped", exception);
    }

    return exception;
}
```

What I am trying to do is to re-throw the same type of exceptions that derived from `MyException` to keep the original stack trace. However I do not want to check for every child of `MyException` with code like:

```
(exception is ChildOfMyException)
    exceptionToReturn = new ChildOfMyException(exception.Message, exception);
```

If I use generics. I cannot specify an explicit constructor.

```
public static Exception Wrap<TException>(TException exception)
    where TException : Exception, new()
{
    Exception exc;
    if (exception is MyException)
    {
        exc = new TException();
    }
    else
    {
        exc = new MyException("Referenced library exception wrapped", exception);
    }
    return exc;
}
```

Is there some way that I am missing or will I have to use reflection to modify  `_innerException` field.

Comment: why not just rethrow?

Comment: Don't wrap all your functions in `try catch` block. Use AOP.

Comment: This is where an exception filter could have come in handy (leaving aside the discussion of whether it's actually safe for you to catch *every* type of exception - it's usually an unsafe assumption). However, they're not available in C#. They exist in IL, so you could access them via some form of post-build re-write. Basically, if they existed in C#, you would have something like `catch(Exception ex) where (!ex is MyException) {}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, if your want to rethrow an exception, use:

```
throw;
```

and not

```
throw ex;
```

The last statement will overwrite your stack trace, the first statement will preserve it.

You can only rethrow an exception inside the catch-block, but not inside anoother method. You could try something like this:

```
try
{
    // Any code
}
catch(MyException ex)
{
    throw;
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    throw Wrap(ex);
}
```

Where your `Wrap` method only wraps the the exceptions that must be wrapped. In essence it becomes this:

```
try
{
    // Any code
}
catch(MyException ex)
{
    throw;
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    throw new MyException("Referenced library exception wrapped", ex);
}
```

If this does not work for you (because try-catch blocks get repeated over and over), you also could take a look at AOP which might do it for you. Using postsharp, your method could become a bit like:

```
[ExceptionPolicy(bla bla)]
void MyMethod()
{
    // Any code
}
```

Read more at: http://www.postsharp.net/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save the original stacktrace and rethrow the original exception you have to `throw` instead of `throw ex`. So your wrap function needs to return a boolean which will indicate a throw or rethrow, along with the new exception if there is any.

Something like this:

```
public static bool Wrap(ref Exception exception) {
    if (exception is MyException) {
        // false indicates a rethrow of the original exception
        return false;
    }
    exception = new MyException("Referenced library exception wrapped", exception);
    return true;
}

// Calling code
try {
    // Something
} catch (Exception ex) {
    if (SomeClass.Wrap(ref ex))
        throw ex;
    throw;
}
```